# Want to hide the 9' wire that comes with an AXTRA 16-receptacle surge protector and plugs into normal outlet

Tags: wiring, surge-suppression

I'm considering buying an AXTRA 16-receptacle surge protector to mount permanently top of my workbench, along the wall. A conventional power receptacle is located 8" above the surface of the workbench on the 48" x 20" wall behind the workbench. The nine-foot cable, which comes from one end of the power strip would have to be curled around, drawn to the center, and then up to that receptacle. Is there a good way to hide that cable?

Answer (score 3):

Cut the cable to whatever length works for you, then install a replacement 3-prong plug. Last time I looked, replacement 5-15P plugs cost anywhere from $3 to $10 at a hardware store.

If you want to do it at almost no cost and you are suitably equipped, remove both ends from the strip, grab the metal plate that covers the back of the strip using a pair of pliers and slide it within its channel a few inches in the direction opposite the cord so as to expose the innards near the switch. De-solder the power cord, unclamp the strain relief and then cut the cord to a suitable length. Strip, solder, clamp, slide back and reassemble. That's how I did it.